# X limits with continuous character values in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, geom-bar

I am creating a bar graph with continuous x-labels of 'Fiscal Years', such as "2009/10", "2010/11", etc. I have a column in my dataset with a specific Fiscal Year that I would like the x-labels to begin at (see example image below). Then, I would like the x-labels to be every continuous Fiscal Year until the present. The last x-label should be "2018/19". When I try to set the limits with `scale_x_continuous`, I receive an error of `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`. However, if I use 'scale_x_discrete', I get a graph with only two bars: my chosen "Start" date and the "End" of 2018/19.

```
Start<-Project_x$Start[c(1)]
End<-"2018/2019"

ggplot(Project_x, (aes(x=`FY`, y=Amount)), na.rm=TRUE)+
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack")+
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(Start,End))

` Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale `
```

Thank you.

My data is:

```
df <- data.frame(Project = c(5, 6, 5, 5, 9, 5), 
             FY = c("2010/11","2017/18","2012/13","2011/12","2003/04","2000/01"),
             Start=c("2010/11", "2011/12", "2010/11", "2010/11", "2001/02", "2010/11"),
             Amount = c(500,502,788,100,78,NA))
```

To use the code in the answer below, I need to base my `Start_Year` off of my `Start` column rather than the `FY` column, and the graph should just be for Project #5.

```
as.tibble(df) %>% 
mutate(Start_Year = as.numeric(sub("/\\d{2}","",Start)))
xlabel_start<-subset(df$Start_Year, Project == 5)
xlabel_end<-2018
filter(between(Start_Year,xlabel_start,xlabel_end)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = FY, y = Amount))+
  geom_col()
```

When running this, my `xlabel_start` is `NULL`.

[image]

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example, somehting like the output of `dput(Project_x)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ggplot`, `continuous` is dedicated for numerical values. Here, your fiscal year are character (or factor) format and so they are considered as `discrete` values and are sorted alphabetically by `ggplot2`.

One possible solution to get your expected plot is to create a new variable containing the starting year of the fiscal year and filter for values between 2010 and 2018.

But first, we are going to isolate the project and the starting year of interest by creating a new dataframe:

```r
library(dplyr)

xlabel_start <- as.tibble(df) %>% 
  mutate(Start_Year = as.numeric(sub("/\\d{2}","",Start))) %>%
  distinct(Project, Start_Year) %>%
  filter(Project == 5)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  Project Start_Year
    <dbl>      <dbl>
1       5       2010
```

Now, using almost the same pipeline, we can isolate values of interest by 
doing:

```r
library(tidyverse)

as.tibble(df) %>% 
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(sub("/\\d{2}","",FY))) %>%
  filter(Project == 5 & between(Year,xlabel_start$Start_Year,xlabel_end))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Project FY      Start   Amount  Year
    <dbl> <fct>   <fct>    <dbl> <dbl>
1       5 2010/11 2010/11    500  2010
2       5 2012/13 2010/11    788  2012
3       5 2011/12 2010/11    100  2011
```

And once you have done this, you can simply add the `ggplot` plotting part at the end of this pipe sequence:

```r
library(tidyverse)

as.tibble(df) %>% 
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(sub("/\\d{2}","",FY))) %>%
  filter(Project == 5 & between(Year,xlabel_start$Start_Year,xlabel_end)) #%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = FY, y = Amount))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Thank you, but I want to avoid manually entering years in the filter function because I will be creating multiple graphs in a loop for projects that have varying Start Years.

Comment: You can definitely pass the starting and ending year as variable before the filter function and reuse them as you wish. I edited my answer accordingly. Let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my answer to specify that I need the start date to be based off of the 'Start' column rather than 'FY'. I expanded the reproducible data example as well.

Comment: Based on what you posted in your edited question, you mis-understood the role of pipes and you introduce some function in the middle that break the sequence and led to a NULL result. I edited my answer to provide a way to get what you are looking for. Let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you for putting up with my beginner knowledge :)